# Total Aggregate Sum of Each Category Retrieved in the Group By Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

[image]

"I have a table like this is which I have used group by with sum() function to calculate 
total participants against each training type held in different districts.now what I want to do is I want total sum for each training type category e.g: for CMST I want total sum of male,female and total participants after CMST and all the other categories something like this:"

[image]

I am displaying this table in my views table and working with mvc entity framework.is it possible to do this via sql query or it would be more appropriate to do it via coding.please suggest the best way to achieve it.

Query which i am using to achieve it is below:

```
select [District_Name] as DISTRICT_NAME,
  [Training_Type],
  sum(Male_Participants) as Male_Participants,
  sum([Female_Participants]) as Female_Participants,
  sum([Total_Participants]) as Total_Participants
   from [TrainingsData]
     where 
    [Training_Type] = 'CMST'
    or 
    [Training_Type] = 'LMST' 
    or 
    [Training_Type] = 'Community Awareness Training  (CAT)' 
        or 
    [Training_Type] = 'Exposure Visit' 
        or 
    [Training_Type] = 'Literacy & Numeracy' 
        or 
    [Training_Type] = 'Orientation Training Workshop (OTW)'
        or 
    [Training_Type] = 'TVET'
  group by [District_Name],[Training_Type]
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to use just `SELECT training_type, SUM(male_paticipants) as males, SUM(female_participants) as females, SUM(male_participants)+SUM(female_participants) as total FROM _tbl GROUP BY training_type`

Comment: You can get totals, and subtotal in T-SQL using [`GROUPING SETS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#group-by-grouping-sets--). So in your case instead of `GROUP BY DISTRICT_NAME, TrainingType`, you would likely use `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((DISTRICT_NAME, TrainingType), (TrainingType))`

Comment: I want output in the form of second table.i.e. showing subtotal for each type of Training type. i dont want the overall total sum.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your desired output with this following script but need some adjustment in your report like replacing the District_name and Training_type in the report part. The condition will be - if District_Name = 'ZZZZZ' then replace both district_name,training_type with '' before display.

```
WITH Tab1(district_name,training_type,male_participants,female_participants,total_participants)
AS
(
    SELECT 'Jhal MAgsi','CMST',10,20,30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Khuzdar','CMST',5,5,10 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Killa Abdullah','CMST',15,15,30 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhal MAgsi','CAT',1,2,3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Khuzdar','CAT',14,20,34 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Loralai','CAT',100,250,350 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Pishin','CAT',1,1,2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhal MAgsi','LN',3,3,6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Khuzdar','LN',9,100,109 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Loralai','LN',200,50,250 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Jhal MAgsi','LMST',5,8,13 UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Khuzdar','LMST',9,5,14
)

SELECT district_name,training_type,male_participants,female_participants,total_participants
FROM Tab1 T1

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ZZZZZ' district_name,
training_type,
SUM(T1.male_participants) male_participants,
SUM(T1.female_participants) female_participants,
SUM(T1.total_participants) total_participants
FROM tab1 T1
GROUP BY training_type
ORDER BY 2,1
```

Output is-

```
district_name   training_type   male_participants   female_participants total_participants
Jhal MAgsi      CAT     1       2       3
Khuzdar         CAT     14      20      34
Loralai         CAT     100     250     350
Pishin          CAT     1       1       2
ZZZZZ           CAT     116     273     389
Jhal MAgsi      CMST    10      20      30
Khuzdar         CMST    5       5       10
Killa Abdullah  CMST    15      15      30
ZZZZZ           CMST    30      40      70
Jhal MAgsi      LMST    5       8       13
Khuzdar         LMST    9       5       14
ZZZZZ           LMST    14      13      27
Jhal MAgsi      LN      3       3       6
Khuzdar         LN      9       100     109
Loralai         LN      200     50      250
ZZZZZ           LN      212     153     365
```

Comment: it is giving the same result as with my query.

Comment: there will be rows after each group, which will contain sum of that group. I have checked and found of here.

Comment: Check the adjusted code. I have added values in place your script and its returning expected results. You just need to consider 'ZZZZZ' rows as Group level details for the above details.

Comment: yes it is working i have to modify it a little for my required results.Thanks

Comment: You are most welcome. Please dont forget to put an up vote and accept the result :)

Comment: there is one little problem it is showing the total of each group correctly but not at the correct number of row.

Comment: it is not showing the sum after the training types of a specific group is listed e.g. it is showing like this .see the image i have updated above

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194925/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-sadia).